# How to configure ldap with spring 4.0

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I am facing issue in authenticating with openldap, I dont know how to configure spring security, ldap with Spring 4.0.0 version. Kindly provide sample reference.

```
<beans:bean id="contextSource"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <beans:constructor-arg
        value="ldap://localhost:389/dc=test,dc=com" />
</beans:bean>
<security:ldap-server id="contextSource"
    url="ldap://localhost:389/dc=test,dc=com" />


<beans:bean id="authMgr"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
                <beans:constructor-arg>
                    <beans:bean
                        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
                        <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                        <beans:property name="userDnPatterns">
                            <beans:list>
                                <beans:value>uid={0},ou=users</beans:value>
                            </beans:list>
                        </beans:property>
                    </beans:bean>
                </beans:constructor-arg>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:ldap-authentication-provider
        server-ref="contextSource" user-search-base="ou=users"
        user-search-filter="(uid={0})" group-search-filter="ou=groups">
        <security:password-compare hash="{sha}"
            password-attribute="userPassword" />
    </security:ldap-authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Security 4.0 LDAP Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/ldap.html)

LDAP best practise would be to search for the DN of the entry, hence configure

```
    <bean id="userSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
      <constructor-arg index="0" value=""/>
      <constructor-arg index="1" value="(uid={0})"/>
      <constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
    </bean>
```

Also typically the LDAP static group entries' naming attribute is `cn`, hence configure

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
    <constructor-arg value="ou=groups"/>
    <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="cn"/>
</bean>
```

instead of the example shown in the guide

Comment: I have edited my question and pasted xml config kindly suggest if any incorrect, also I am getting error as "LDAP: error code 34 - invalid DN" though I have entered correct DN.

Comment: I am getting bad credential exception though I have entered correct password. In ldap i have configured password encryption as sha and same in spring xml.

Comment: Guys please help its urgent !

Comment: LDAP best practise is to let the LDAP Server do the password comparison when the client sends an LDAP BIND request. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/ldap.html#ldap-ldap-authenticators-bind